# Picamera: intermitent purple snowstorm - EMI or software issue?

Tags: raspicam, video-input

I have recently tried a NoIR camera in my new appartment and started getting this strange interference, see photo below. I comes and goes randomly but happens mostly at night in a dark room. Sometimes it can go on a whole night, every minute or so, and sometimes just for minute.

I have used the same setup on a Pi0w and on a Pi2+ before without this problem and I do not think the software has changed.

- Pi3+ with Buster
- Pihut Zerocam NOir https://thepihut.com/products/zerocam-noir-camera-for-raspberry-pi-zero
- Ribbon cable is extended to 45 cm

**Could this be some sort of magnetic interference or should I be looking at hardware or software issues?
What can I do about it?**
[image]

Comment: Software issue. Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` to resolve it.

Comment: Great! I will  try that and get back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Thanks @[Dougie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/94397/dougie)

That seems to fix it.

Apparently there is a new AWB algorithm to accomodate the Pi4 and this screws with PiNoIR cameras on older pi's The whole discussion is found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=245994

By now it seems to be included in the standard upgrade. I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` as Dougie suggested and have not hade any problems since.

So all cred to Dougie and guys on pi-f